# Is multi-part question (with open bounty) too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, bounty

I'm wondering if the question [Serving 3D Via WFS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198915) is too broad.  In fact, the user admits that it is in the question and there are three separate questions in the question.

> 1. What is/are the standard(s) for serving 3D geometry in WFS?
> 2. What programs actually support these standards? (Does anyone know if
>      TerraExplorer and GeoServer supports them?)
> 3. Are there any accepted non-standard ways of accomplishing this?

Normally, I'd vote to close the question until the OP edits the question or posts separate questions.  However, the question has an open bounty and therefore can't be closed. Also, I think it's fairly obvious what the OP is trying to do, but normally, wouldn't these types of questions be closed?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is too broad too.

My feeling is that multi-part questions are not in the spirit of bounties (nor the site in general), and irrespective of the bounty I think it should be closed.

I have determined that the [bounty can be refunded by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties), which I have done, so that this question can be placed On Hold pending the question being further focussed.